# Ripple effect not showing on navigation drawer item clicked state

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

my NavigationView:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/black"
    app:itemBackground="?attr/selectableItemBackground" />
```

drawer.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group
    android:id="@+id/mainActions"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/firm"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/firm"
        android:title="@string/firm" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/surveys"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/surveys"
        android:title="@string/surveys" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/results"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/results"
        android:title="@string/results" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/notifications"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/notifications"
        android:title="@string/notifications" />

</group>

<group
    android:id="@+id/subActions"
    android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/settings"
        android:title="@string/settings" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/logout"
        android:title="@string/logout" />

</group>
```

I am running the app on Android 6 Galaxy Note 4 device. When I press each navigation drawer item only the color of the icon is changed to light blue. i would like to change also the text color of each item and have ripple effect shown.

Comment: How about removing `app:itemBackground="attr/selectableItemBackground"`?. Maybe it's enabled by default.

Comment: removing this attribute adds only the default static grey background to the item which is undesirable in my case...

Answer (score 1):

Set a `color` selector for the

```
app:itemTextColor="@color/selector_nav_items"
```

Where the selector itself is
`res/color/selector_nav_items`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/your_light_blue_color" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/black"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: i have resolved this part of my question...but what about the ripple effect?